# How does `onViewStateRestored` from Fragments work?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, viewstate, restore

I am really confused with the internal state of a Fragment. 
I have an Activity holding only one Fragment at once and replaces it, if another Fragment should get shown. From the docs `onSaveInstanceState` is called *ONLY* if the Activitys `onSaveInstanceState` is getting called (which isn't called in my case).

If I stop my Fragment, I'll store its state myself inside a Singleton (yeah, I know I hate Singletons, too, but wasn't my idea to do so). 
So I have to recreate the whole `ViewHirarchy`, create new Views (by using the keyword `new`), restore its state and return them in `onCreateView`.
I also have a Checkbox inside this View from which I explicitly do *NOT* want to store its state.

However the `FragmentManager` wants to be "intelligent" and calls `onViewStateRestored` with a Bundle I never created myself, and "restores" the state of the old `CheckBox` and applies it to my NEW CheckBox. This throws up so many questions:

Can I control the bundle from `onViewStateRestored`?

How does the FragmentManager take the state of a (probably garbage-collected) CheckBox and applies it to the new one?

Why does it only save the state of the Checkbox (Not of TextViews??)

So to sum it up: How does `onViewStateRestored` work?

Note I'm using Fragmentv4, so no API > 17 required for `onViewStateRestored`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well, sometimes fragments can get a little confusing, but after a while you will get used to them, and learn that they are your friends after all.

If on the onCreate() method of your fragment, you do: setRetainInstance(true); The visible state of your views will be kept, otherwise it won't.

Suppose a fragment called "f" of class F, its lifecycle would go like this:
- When instantiating/attaching/showing it, those are the f's methods that are called, in this order:

```
F.newInstance();
F();
F.onCreate();
F.onCreateView();
F.onViewStateRestored;
F.onResume();
```

At this point, your fragment will be visible on the screen.
Assume, that the device is rotated, therefore, the fragment information must be preserved, this is the flow of events triggered by the rotation:

```
F.onSaveInstanceState(); //save your info, before the fragment is destroyed, HERE YOU CAN CONTROL THE SAVED BUNDLE, CHECK EXAMPLE BELLOW.
F.onDestroyView(); //destroy any extra allocations your have made
//here starts f's restore process
F.onCreateView(); //f's view will be recreated
F.onViewStateRestored(); //load your info and restore the state of f's view
F.onResume(); //this method is called when your fragment is restoring its focus, sometimes you will need to insert some code here.


//store the information using the correct types, according to your variables.
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("foo", this.foo);
    outState.putBoolean("bar", true);
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle inState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(inState);
    if(inState!=null) {
        if (inState.getBoolean("bar", false)) {
            this.foo = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double>>) inState.getSerializable("foo");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer seems to imply that `F()` and `F.onCreate()` are not called on configuration change (e.g. screen orientation change). This is not true. Both are indeed called.

Comment: Please also be aware that `onSaveInstanceState` is actually invoked right after you fragment getting into the background. After `onSaveInstanceState`, `onDestroy` is not always necessary to be called.