# android app crashes after accepting request permission in API 23

Tags: android

this code works fine in API 24 but app crashes in API 23 just after the permission is given by user..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    isPermissionGranted();
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.v("", "Permission: " + permissions[0] + "was " + grantResults[0]);
        permissionGranted();
    }
}



public  void isPermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("","Permission is granted");
            permissionGranted();
        } else {
            Log.v("","Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v("","Permission is granted");
        permissionGranted();
    }
}

//called after permission given by user
public void permissionGranted(){
    SystemChanges systemChanges = new SystemChanges();
    systemChanges.setStatusBarColor(this);
    mainFragment();
}

//inflate the main fragment
public void mainFragment(){
    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentMain, mainFragment, "mainFragment");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

error that it gives in API 23

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.anshul.player/com.example.anshul.player.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40267990/caused-by-java-lang-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-on

Comment: You are starting to check for permission before your activity is initialised. Make the call in onResume() at least, although you should call it when is needed not at start of activity

Comment: @X3Btel it's giving the same error in onResme()

Comment: post your 'mainFragment();' ..code

Comment: give these permission at run time when you required. In some cases it is not working as for you also

Comment: @Raghavendra i tried over riding onSavedInstanceState but deosn't work

Comment: @Anshul.. I hope you have tried this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575921/illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-wit

Comment: @Raghavendra it works but doesn't show every fragment how it should on the first time, if i open the app second time it does

Comment: @Raghavendra it works, actually earlier i'd put the code in onResume, thanks :)